# Multiple submit on one form

Tags: php, forms

I have two buttons for a register form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Pay Now" class="submit" id="submit1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Pay Later" class="submit" id="submit2" />
```

Check to see if either button is pushed

```
if((isset($_POST['submit1'])) or (isset($_POST['submit2'])))
```

Then PHP code to sanitize and validate data for either input

Now I want to have the "Pay Now" go to one page, and the "Pay Later" go to a different page, but I can n not figure it out.  Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that in php you need to use `||` instead of `or`

Comment: And the extra brackets around `isset` aren't needed

Comment: And also... What is your question excactly? Do you need to know how to redirect pages in php?

Comment: @Joren He can use `or` keyword instead of `||`. They are the same (but not equal, `or` got lower priority).

Comment: Joren, thanks.  Yes, I want to redirect to different pages, depending on which button is pushed, but after the validation code.

Comment: What I do is to set a flag in a hidden input with JQuery depending on the button pressed then I submit the form through javascript. That might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION`. After set session, redirect page and get session data

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) || isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;

    if($_POST['submit1'])
        header("Location: pay_now.php");
    elseif($_POST['submit2'])
        header("Location: pay_later.php");
}
```

#### pay_now.php or pay_later.php

```
$data = $_SESSION['post'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use form action like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Pay Now" class="submit" id="submit1" onclick="this.form.action='page1.php'" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Pay Later" class="submit" id="submit2" onclick="this.form.action='page2.php'" />

</form>
```

Comment: Just need to note that this means the input sanitization must be in both scripts. It can be put in an `include` script that they share.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if($_POST['submit'] == 'Pay Now')
  {
   echo $_POST['submit'];

  }
  if($_POST['submit'] == 'Pay Later')
  {
   echo  $_POST['submit']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP but you can also do it in JS using onlick event.

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="dynamicForm">
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="submit" id="submit1" onclick="buttonClicked(1);" />
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Pay Later" class="submit" id="submit2" onclick="buttonClicked(2);" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClicked(type) {
        if (type === 1) {
           document.dynamicForm.action = 'firstUrl';
        } else {
           document.dynamicForm.action = 'secondUrl';
        }
        document.dynamicForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```